"Index of/" shows instead of React page when starting app with 'npm start'
I just installed React and tried creating a demo app, 'my-app'. I switched to that directory and started that app with 'npm start' expecting that I would get the blue logo with the grey background. Instead, I got this
The my-app folder is in username/Documents. However, the directory shown above is in the username/Project folder. As I mentioned earlier, I did make sure I was in my-app, so I'm not sure why React went to this directory.
The ID-Wallet folder shown in the picture contains an index.html file. Is that the problem, even though my-app is in a completely different folder?
I also got this warning
EDIT:
I tried removing the index.html file in Documents/ID-Wallet but it changed nothing.
Any thoughts?
Thank you
OS: macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
Chip: M2

SOLVED:
So the issue was that username/Project was open in VS code while I was trying to run the app in the terminal. I guess React tries to open the app that is in VS code even if you told it to start a different app ‍♀️
